# Problems with FormControl and AbstractControl in angular

Tags: angular, forms, form-control, angular-abstract-control

I'm following a online course but I have lots of problems with that.

I depends on I put on my code I get

> type 'abstractcontrol' is missing the following properties from type 'formcontrol': registerOnChange, registerOnDisable, _applyFormState

or

> type Abstractcontrol is not assignable to type formcontrol

In the TS of my Component I have

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {  FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { DestinoViaje } from '../models/destino-viaje.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-destino-viaje',
  templateUrl: './form-destino-viaje.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-destino-viaje.component.css']
})
export class FormDestinoViajeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onItemAdded: EventEmitter<DestinoViaje>;
  fg: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.onItemAdded = new EventEmitter();
    this.fg = fb.group({
      nombre: [''],
      url: ['']
    });
    console.log(this.fg);

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {


  }

  guardar(nombre: string, url: string): boolean {
    let d = new DestinoViaje(nombre, url);
    this.onItemAdded.emit(d);
    return false;

  }

}
```

and in the HTML of my Component I Have

```
<form
        [formGroup]="fg"
        (ngSubmit)="guardar(
                                fg.controls['nombre'].value,
                                fg.controls['url'].value
                    )">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
            id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresar nombre..."
            [formControl]="fg.controls['nombre']">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Imagen Url">Imagen Url</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
            id="imagenUrl" placeholder="Ingresar url..."
            [formControl]="fg.controls['url']">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar!</button>
</form>
```

I'm not sure in which version the example is, but I'm using Angular 11.05

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `nombre` and `url` are not control fields, you are making them an array of an empty string. you should create them like

```js
this.fg = fb.group({
      nombre: this.fb.control(/*initial value*/'', /*validators that they should pass*/[]')',
      url:this.fb.control(/*initial value*/'', /*validators that they should pass*/[]')'
});
```

So you create a `FormControl` instead of `Array<string>`

#### Here's a template sample using reactive forms:

```html
<!-- component.template.html -->

<form [formGroup]="group">
    <input type="email" formControlName="email">
    <input type="password" formControlName="passw">
    <!-- more inputs maybe -->
</form>
```

```js
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

    // This is our reactive form that we want to use
    group: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        const fb = this.fb; // So we write less code
        this.group = fb.group({
            // On the left side we use the formControlName that we are going to use in the html
            // then, on the control we pass the default value of the input and an array of validators. 
            // Validators are just functions that may return errors given a certain control input.
            email: fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
            // Remember that passw is what we used on the formControlName of the template
            passw: fb.control('', [Validators.required])
        });
    }

}
```

#### Some notes:

Given your confusion, if you check [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) you will see that there's an example doing what you did:

Just using a `FormControl` in case you have a single input that doesn't belong to any `<form>` or `FormGroup`. When you have a full form, if you scroll down, you'll see an example that looks more what I gave you in my last edit of my answer.

#### Final answer

No it's not because different versions of Angular but different use-cases of the `ReactiveForms` of Angular. One uses a form and the other does not.

Comment: I've change my code for -- this.fg = fb.group({
      nombre: fb.control(/*initial value*/'', /*validators that they should pass*/[]),
      url: fb.control(/*initial value*/'', /*validators that they should pass*/[])
    })--
But the console is still saying "Type AbstractControl is not assignable to type FormControl" in my html code [formControl]="fg.controls['nombre']"

Comment: lol... the problem is formControl is not the correct way (I think).. I've changed it for
formControlName='url' and It works!!
Could you tell me if it is for a difference between versions? Because I don't understand why the video I saw before has that code... Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry to reply so late. In my timezone was sleep time .
Next time please edit your question and just send me a comment because it's really hard to read the code that you have just pasted in the comments here.
As I see it, *yes indeed*, you were also missing `formControlName` in your `input`s of your form. I really can't judge since I've not seen your video but forms have always been like this. Use the directive `[formGroup]="form"` on your `<form>` HTML element and then you use the directive `formControlName` on the inputs passing the "key" of the control as the value. Let me show you

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details about the problems you were facing :)

Comment: Thank you so much. But I still don't understand why the teacher's code runs and when I tried it didn't. Now I know I have to use formControlName when I use FormGroup and I have to use FormControl when I use a single input control. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too, then I have changed: **fg: FormGroup;** on **fg: any;**